# Simple way to split two numbers

Tags: c#, split

My data reader reads the rows I want to split the result from the reader and take the second digit. So for example number is 42 I w want the 2. How can I accomplish this easily. There is about a million ways i have seen but none very simplistic. Thank you in advance!

```
 ld.ScaleGroup = (ScaleGroup)reader["ScaleGroup"];
 string[] split = ld.ScaleGroup.ToString().Split(?);
```

Comment: What is `ScaleGroup`? You cannot cast the reader to it. If it's an `int` you should use `reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("ScaleGroup"))`, then you could use `ToString` to convert it to a `string` which has an indexer to access a char.

Comment: look into `string.ToCharArray()`

Comment: @ja72: why `ToCharArray`, he can access a char directly: `char second="42"[1];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `Split()` if you just want the 2nd character. Just write:

```
string str = ld.ScaleGroup.ToString();
char secondDigit = str[1];
```

Make sure `str` really has at least 2 characters, of course.

**EDIT:** If you want it as a string, see D Stanley's answer using `Substring()`.

`Split()` is used for strings that consist of a sequence of tokens, separated by a delimiter character (or characters). For example, splitting `"a,b,c"` using the delimiter `,` would return an array of 3 strings `"a"`, `"b"` and `"c"`.

Answer (score 7):

If you *always* want the second digit you can do

```
ld.ScaleGroup.ToString().Substring(1,1);
```

But what about numbers < 10?  > 100?

Or if you always want the *ones* digit (e.g. 123 -> 3) then take the number mod 10:

```
int ones = ld.ScaleGroup % 10;
```

Comment: +1 especially for `%` - not sure what the point of converting number to string to perform some computation on it...